# How do I use a git tag to display all the files that have changed in that tag?

Tags: git, bash

I have a git tag and I need to see the file(s) which changed during the commit which is tagged by the tag.

I am using this however it shows me other details as well such as Tagger name, some blank spaces, tag message etc.

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only ${TAG_NAME}
```

I only want to see the file(s) and nothing else. I have tried grep however as the message is different everytime that wouldn't work. Please let me know your views and solutions :)

Comment: Add a space in the format: `git show --pretty="format: " --name-only ${TAG_NAME}` works for me

Comment: FWIW, it works for me with or without the space.

Comment: Probably different versions of git, looks like format: takes a string, some versions may not detect an empty string as a string

Comment: Actually, I thought it worked but it hasn't, this is the response I'm getting. 

$ git show --pretty="format: " --name-only QC_1788 
tag QC_1788 
Tagger: xyz 
tag message 
ClusterUtilsResources.properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get a simple file list when I use:

```
git diff --name-only tag-name tag-name^
```

e.g., on the git repo itself I can do this

```
$ git diff --name-only v1.8.4.4 v1.8.4.4^
Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.4.4.txt
Documentation/git.txt
RelNotes
```

Comment: Thanks this works, here is the proof : 
    $ git diff --name-only QC_1788 QC_1788^  ClusterUtilsResources.properties